# How do I Scrape <h1> <h2> and save to text file inVBScript

Tags: vbscript, getelementbyid, getelementsbytagname, getelementsbyclassname

I'm new here. Writing VBScript code from samples on the web. I'm trying to grab the `<h1>` and `<h2>` text from a web page and save it to a text file. Below is a sample of the web page data, followed by some of my failed code. Running Windows 7 home premium on PC.

'THIS IS THE WEB PAGE I'M ACCESSING ===========

```
<body>
<div class stuff
<div id stuff

<div class="header-info">
    <h1>The Girl I Love</h1>
    <h2>Tony Bennet</h2>

<more div stuff
```

'HERE IS MY CODE ==============================

```
'=== attach to an already running IE instance:
Set app = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
For Each window In app.Windows()
  If InStr(1, window.FullName, "iexplore", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
    Set ie = window
    Exit For
  End If
Next

'Set up text file to write to
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f = fso.OpenTextFile("c:\users\kp\desktop\output.txt", 2, True, -1)

'Various Code line tests - and results
f.Write ie.document.body 'returns [object HTMLBodyElement]
f.Write ie.document.body.innerText 'returns all body text
f.Write ie.document.getElementsByClassName("header-info")   'returns [object HTMLCollection]
f.Write ie.document.getElementsByTagName("<h1>") 'returns [object HTMLCollection]
f.Write ie.document.getElementsByTagName("<h1>").innerText 'FAILS not valid

kpmsg = "you're done"
Wscript.echo kpmsg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full program is here https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=E2F0CE17A268A4FA%21348

```
Set Arg = WScript.Arguments
set WshShell = createObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set Inp = WScript.Stdin
Set Outp = Wscript.Stdout

Sub HttpGet
On Error Resume Next
'   Have to use MSXML2 as Microsoft.XMLHTTP caused Access Denied errors after the page had been repeatedly gotten, go figure that one
'   Set File = WScript.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.4.0")
    Set File = WScript.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    File.Open "GET", Arg(1), False
    File.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0; Trident/4.0; SLCC1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; Media Center PC 5.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30618; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; BCD2000; BCD2000)"
    File.Send
    txt=File.ResponseText
    'Putting in line endings
    Outp.write txt
    If err.number <> 0 then 
        Outp.writeline "" 
        Outp.writeline "Error getting file" 
        Outp.writeline "==================" 
        Outp.writeline "" 
        Outp.writeline "Error " & err.number & "(0x" & hex(err.number) & ") " & err.description 
        Outp.writeline "Source " & err.source 
        Outp.writeline "" 
        Outp.writeline "HTTP Error " & File.Status & " " & File.StatusText
        Outp.writeline  File.getAllResponseHeaders
        Outp.writeline LCase(Arg(1))
    End If
End Sub

'=============================================
Sub RemoveHTMLTags
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") 
    ie.Visible = 0
    ie.Silent = 1 
    ie.Navigate2 "file://" & FilterPath & "Filter.html"
    Do 
        wscript.sleep 50            

    Loop Until ie.document.readystate = "complete"
    ie.document.body.innerhtml = Inp.readall
    Outp.write ie.document.body.innertext
'   ie.quit
End Sub
```

Filter is for use in a command prompt. Filter.vbs must be run with cscript.exe. If you just type filter it will run a batch file that will do this automatically.

```
filter subcommand [parameters]
```

Filter reads and writes standard in and standard out only. These are only available in a command prompt.

```
filter <inputfile >outputfile
filter <inputfile | other_command
other_command | filter >outputfile
other_command | filter | other_command
```

Use

**Web**

```
filter web webaddress
filter ip webaddress
```

Retrieves a file from the web and writes it to standard out.

```
webaddress - a web address fully specified including http://
```

**Example**

Gets Microsoft's home page

```
filter web http://www.microsoft.com
```

**Tags**

```
filter tags
```

Removes HTML tags from text.

**Example**

```
filter web http://www.microsoft.com | filter tags
```

Collections are read `for each thing in collection:statements:Next`